# How to count OpportunityLineItems left in an after delete OpportunityLineItems

Tags: trigger, soql, opportunity, opportunity-lineitem

I have a trigger on the `OpportunityLineItem` acting `after delete`. From that trigger, I want to query all the `Opportunities` associated to the `OpportunityLineItems` deleted to see if they still have other `OpportunityLineItems` associated to them.

The `Opportunity` SObject has to field that should help me with that:

- `HasOpportunityLineItem`
- `TotalOpportunityQuantity`

The problem is that the value of this field doesn't seem to be accurate when I query it `after` the action.

Am I missing something? If not, what is an efficient way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1):

"Formula" style fields, such as HasOpportunityLineItem and TotalOpportunityQuantity, are not *set* until after all triggers have executed. They are updated in the same phase as normal rollup summary fields. See the [Triggers and Order of Execution](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm) for more information on the specific order of operations. You'll need to run a query to find out what's left.

```
Set<Id> oppIds = new Set<Id>(), remainIds = new Set<Id>();
for(OpportunityLineItem record: Trigger.old) {
    oppIds.add(record.OpportunityId);
}
for(AggregateResult result: [SELECT Count(Id) Sum, OpportunityId oppId FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE OpportunityId in :oppIds GROUP BY OpportunityId]) {
    remainIds.add((Id)result.get('oppId'));
}
// remainIds now contains all records that have at least one other item still
```

There are other means of reaching this conclusion, but this would be one straight-forward way of determining which opportunities still have line items.

Answer (score 0):

AggregateResult ar = [Select Count(ID) From OpportunityLineItem where OpportunityID = :oppID];

Comment: Eric -- I think you should modify this answer to be bulkified as it will execute within the OLI trigger